# Probabilistic principal component regression

Tags: regression, pca, maximum-likelihood

There is a [paper by Bishop and Tipping](https://rss.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/1467-9868.00196) where they show that Principal Component Analysis can be seen as a limit of the MLE for a probabilistic model.

Is there a similar view of Principal Component Regression?